# C# generic type constraints - prevent type parameters from being the same?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Consider the following generic:

```
class Foo<T, U> {}
```

Is it possible to prevent T and U from being the same type?  This question is borne out of curiosity.

Comment: I assume you're not looking for answers that impose massive additional constraints (e.g. T : class, U : struct, or different inheritance hierarchies) :-)

Comment: Not at compile time. But obviously you could do it at runtime through exception :)

Comment: It's a thought experiment.  The static constructor proposed in one answer is interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not. The only options you have are listed here [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970%28v=vs.80%29.aspx shows us that there are 6 kinds of constraint. Equality is not included.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others, you can not use Type Constraints but you can still add runtime checks using static constructors. See http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_25.1.5_Static_constructors_in_generic_classes

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't such a thing. But you might want to look into other languages with template metaprogramming, such as [D](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/) -- they are much more powerful, compile-time variants of generics.